# How to create and add controls in run time with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I don't know how to implement a method with a separate thread using the BackgroundWorker in WinForms. 
I want this method (after every click on a button) to perform:

- create ProgressBar (each new one under the previous one)
- create Bitmap and BackgroundWorker
- set color of every pixel in that Bitmap in the separate thread using BackgroundWorker
- display a precentage progress on the ProgressBar
- after completing: create a new form with bitmap on the background
- after completing: remove the ProgressBar

My code:

```
    List<BackgroundWorker> Workers;
    List<ProgressBar> Progress;
    int OperationsCount = 0;
    private void ShowProgress(int n, int percent)
    {
        Progress[n].Value = percent;
    }
    private void Blend(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap BlendedImage = ... // creates a bitmap
        for (int i = 0; i < BlendedImage.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < BlendedImage.Height; j++)
            {
                ... //changing colour of every pixel
            }
            this.Invoke(new Action(()=>ShowProgress((int)e.Argument, (int)(100 * (double)(i/BlendedImage.Width)))));
        }

        Form BlendedImage_Form = new Form();
        BlendedImage_Form.Size = new Size(BlendedImage.Width, BlendedImage.Height);
        BlendedImage_Form.BackgroundImage = BlendedImage;
        BlendedImage_Form.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => BlendedImage_Form.Show()));

    }        
    private void PerformBlending_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = OperationsCount++;
        Progress.Add(new ProgressBar());
        Progress[n].Size = ...
        Progress[n].Location = ...
        Progress[n].Maximum = 100;
        this.Controls.Add(Progress[n]);

        Workers.Add(new BackgroundWorker());
        Workers[n].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Blend);
        Workers[n].RunWorkerCompleted += (object _sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs _e) => 
        {
            //OperationsCount--;
            //Progress[n].Dispose();
            //this.Controls.Remove(Progress[n]);
            //Progress.RemoveAt(n);
        };
        Workers[n].RunWorkerAsync(n);
    }
```

When I click the button only once then everything seems to be good but when I click the button two times then program:

- creates the first ProgressBar which shows progress correctly and the new form and bitmap are displayed also correctly
- creates the second ProgressBar but it doesn't show the progress at all and no form and no bitmap is displayed.

PS I'd rather use BackgroundWorker than other tools.

Comment: Where do you instantiate these lists?

Comment: All UI work should be on main thread. Even you are using BackgroundWoker you need to modify control on main thread.

Comment: @Groo in public MainWindow()

Comment: (double)(i/BlendedImage.Width) is a standard C# bug, it always produces 0.  You must demand a floating point division, ((double)i / BlendedImage.Width)

Comment: @Adrian How to return the bitmap after changing colour of pixels then? I need it to display it in my form

Comment: @HansPassant Oh yeah, I've changed it before posting it, I forgot to change it here too. So problem still exists :(

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan check my answer, you can safely call from any thread.

Comment: Post the exact complete code, the bug (apart from what Hans wrote) doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: @Groo [code](https://pastebin.com/45jQXCt9)

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan Try with putting create instance code in the invoke in DoWork(), it should work.

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan: are you sure this is your *exact* code? Is the `RunWorkerCompleted` part commented out in your code or not? Because this part has a but that it removes the last picture, but doesn't remove the last `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @Adrian You mean that: [code](https://pastebin.com/LLJECgjq) ?

Comment: @Groo If I uncomment the `RunWorkerCompleted` part then there is out of index error immediately after clicking the button two times. It's like the second BackgroundWorker stops the first one.

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan yes.

Comment: @Adrian it didn't help :(

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan: the code is no doubt prone to race conditions, because you update a global array from multiple threads (well, from a UI thread each time, but invoked from multiple threads). So, the first time you do `progress.RemoveAt(n)`, all other bars will shift one index lower (you won't notice this in the UI since there will be a gap, but the list won't have a gap). I would rewrite that whole part to remove the global counter and the way you index the array, but the point is that (with that commented out) there should be no reason why the second progress bar wouldn't be added.

Comment: @Groo [code](https://pastebin.com/TvXZtLKu) What about that? It doesn't show the progress now and it still terminates the first BackgroundWorker when I click the button second time.

Comment: Is your code make any exception

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TvXZtLKu - no exceptions

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan: one issue might be that you are adding these controls twice to the form (once inside the designer file, once inside the constructor), but right now I have to go so I don't have time to actually run it.

Comment: @TheMelancholicMan: anyway, why don't you simply add this inside the `RunWorkerCompleted`: `if(e.Error != null) MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());` and see the exception?

Comment: @Groo Oh.. I didn't know it. And the problem is probably solved.
`Image1 = Picture1.Image.Clone()`
instead of
`Image1 = Picture1.Image`

Answer (score -1):

As per your comment here is the solution

```
 public void DoSomething()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(()=> DoSomething()));
            }
            else
            {
               // update the ui from here, no worries
            }
        }
```

In this code, I am modifying the object on main thread. If the calls made from non-UI thread this will goes in InvokeRequired.

// From this code you given in comment

https://pastebin.com/45jQXCt9

Please try with making instance inside invoke. It should work.